# Add space between two images

Tags: spacing, graphics

Hello I want add space between two images like this:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test1.png}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test2.png}
    \caption{ActionButton}
    \label{ActionButton}
\end{figure}
```

but it's add space between test2.png and the caption...

How can I solve it?

Comment: The solution here is really simple: You need to be in vertical mode for `\vspace` to have any effect. As such, insert a blank line (or explicit `\par`) after `test1.png`.

Comment: I believe even \newline will do.

Comment: Yes! \par (or a blank line) and \vspace{2cm} after works! Why I shoud add \par? Why here I'm in horizontal mode and not in vertical mode?

Comment: Compare your problem with my comment http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215590/when-to-use-to-address-an-argument/215607#comment506172_215607

Answer (score 29):

I hope that this is the one you want

code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{albt.png}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{altman.png}
   \vspace{0.1cm}
    \caption{ActionButton}
    \label{ActionButton}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image: space]

Answer (score 13):

If the two images are next to each other use horizontal space and not vertical space

```
\hspace{2 cm}
```

Comment: This is better-suited as a comment.

Comment: @Werner he doesn't have enough rep for comment yet :)

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă: That's always the case with a new user. They're also unregistered and most likely will not return to this account.

Comment: @Werner I think they do not return because of discouraging comments like yours.

Comment: @MrigankPawagi: Which comment do you consider discouraging? The user hung around for 1.5 year after my comments and hasn't been seen since late 2019.

Comment: @Werner You are right, and it turned out exactly as you predicted in 2018. However, I feel that your comment in 2017 was anticipating things a bit too early.

Answer (score 11):

You can also just add an \\ after the first includegraphics:

```
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test1.png}\\
    \vspace{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test2.png}
    \caption{ActionButton}
    \label{ActionButton}
\end{figure}
```