# When to use {} to address an argument

Tags: tex-core

When is it necessary to use `{}` to squeeze an argument to a command?

Example:
In TeX we see a lot of calls like `\vskip\onelineskip`
while this macro (`\vskip`) is defined to take one argument.
Would it be better to write `\vskip{\onelineskip}` instead?

Comment: Oh, this question is very very unspecific. It depends at what level you are acting. TeX and LaTeX are different things, needing different input and behaving differently.

Comment: it is never correct to write `\vskip{...}`.  you are probably thinking of the latex `\vspace{...}`, which *does* require a braced argument.

Comment: I am working on Latex (XeTatex), but I thought that the level is unimportant since Tex commands work on Latex as well?

Comment: But they are two different things nontheless and you have to respect the language/grammar/syntax, respectively. You can use low-level `\vskip 10pt` or high-level `\vspace{10pt}`. But you can't mix it up (as @barbara already mentioned).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\vskip` is not a macro, but a TeX primitive and it has a different syntax than macros with arguments.

The syntax is

```
\vskip<glue specification>
```

where `<glue specification>` can basically be a skip register or an explicit glue such as

```
\vskip 1pt plus 2pt minus 1pt
```

See the TeXbook or TeX by Topic for more information.

On the other hand, the LaTeX *macro* `\vspace` takes an argument. If this argument is a single token (a named skip register, for example), braces can be omitted, so

```
\vspace\onelineskip
```

or

```
\vspace{\onelineskip}
```

are equivalent. But

```
\vskip{\onelineskip}
```

will result in an error message.

Comment: There is also a case, where a macro can force curly braces even for single tokens by appending `#` at the end of its parameter text.

Comment: Moreover, `\vskip 1cm` does not the same as `\vspace{1cm}` because `\vspace` is implemented (roughly speaking) by TeX primitives `\vadjust{\vskip<param>}` and it inserts the vertical glue between lines in the paragraph without ending paragraph. On the other hand `\vskip` alone ends the paragraph (because `\par` token is inserted) and then the vertical glue is inserted. The mentioned `\vadjust` in `\vspace` macro is source of misunderstanding of many LaTeX beginners. Another source of potential problem is the undelimited `\vskip` parameter (1cm without plus minus), but this is another story...

Comment: @wipet `\vspace` uses `\vadjust` only when issued in horizontal mode. I usually recommend using it only between paragraphs.